# Regex matching of incomplete strings "as-you-type"

Tags: ruby, regex

What would be a good practice to match strings while the user is typing them in?

I would like to take this regex for matching a time as an example:
`/(\d\d?)(:\d\d?)?\s?(am|pm)?/` matches `12:30 am`, `9 pm`, `23:00` perfectly fine.

It only becomes tricky when you want to provide feedback while the user is typing in that string.
`12:` is not matched, neither would `12:30 p`.

My solution would be to use a second, independend, regex for for the matching of incomplete strings that includes all input possibilities:
`/(\d\d?)(:\d\d?|:)?\s?(|a|p|am|pm)?/` will match `12:` and `12:30 p` just fine.

Is there a better, more elegant way, to do this?

Comment: ewwww. use 2 text fields for the times and a select from am/pm so that you can validate them independently. your current example will accept 99:99pm as a valid entry.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but an additional validation is done independently anyways and additional input fields are not an option.

Comment: @TomDunning this question can be generalized to phone number, credit card numbers, dates, etc. so the general question is of interest beyond formatting time.

Comment: I know it's been a long time ago, but your regex could be simplified to `(\d\d?)(:\d{0,2})?\s?([ap]m?)?`